# how to capture change event in input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

```
$('input').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
$('input').val(1);
```

This dont work. I need capture the change input with JavaScript :-s

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The "change" handler you've got is fine, assuming you're calling it at an appropriate time (i.e., in a `<script>` tag after all the `<input>` elements on the page, or inside a "ready" or "load" handler).  I interpreted your question as being about the fact that the call to `.val()` does not trigger the "change" handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Programmatic changes to `<input>` elements don't cause events. Only user interaction does.

You can do this however:

```
$('input').val(1).trigger('change');
```

Comment: He's asking how to capture the event, not how to throw it :)

Comment: @mattytommo the problem is that **there is no event created** when you programmatically change the value of an element like that. The "change" event handler already there is fine for catching the event.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise he's trying to throw the event himself, my bad. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put those functions inside the "Ready" function. see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SfjJQ/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
    $('input').val(1);
    $('input').trigger('change');
});​
```

keep in mind that your:

```
$('input').val(1);
```

initializes the input to have a value of 1.

Of course you could also do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input')
        .change(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        })
        .val(1)
        .trigger('change');
});​
```

Comment: No event is triggered by the call to `.val()`.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that Mr. User expected the call to `.val(1)` to trigger the "change" handler. I could be wrong; the question is sparse and enigmatic.

Comment: yeah i see what you mean, I added another line to trigger the change event at page load.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, .val() does not trigger any events; however, you could add a wrapper function to jQuery that will change the value and trigger the event if wanted:

```
$( function () {

    //-- new jQuery function
    $.fn.changeVal = function () {
        $.fn.val.apply( this, arguments );
        $( this ).trigger( 'change' );
    };

    //-- your updated code
    $('input').change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
    $('input').changeVal(1);

} );​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bA3V2/